# Payout after loosing all in bet

Tags: rules

9 position Hold em game pays top four positions. Four players remaining short stack goes all in looses. Does he still get payout?

Comment: Little confused with the wording here? Are you saying 4 players remaining, short stack busts and paying out 4? Why wouldn't they get paid if the game pays 4 and the player in 4th busts?

Answer (score 2):

Standard tournament rules are that when more than one player busts, the places are awarded according to starting stack size. So, if there are five players, and a three-way all in busts two, the player who started the hand with the smaller stack is given fifth place and the other is given fourth.